# JS Regex for first letters only, but if the word it only two letters keep both AND numbers as is

Tags: javascript, regex, string, reactjs

Good day,

Is there a way to have a regex that works like so:

Say the word is, **79 Banana AK**

I would want the result to be **79BAK**

So **Lemon 99 B3** would be **L99B3**

I've been playing around and managed to implement a regex that gets the first letters and keeps the full length of the number, but I can't figure out how to maintain the two letter words...

Here is the regex I currently have: `let initials = title.match(/\b([a-zA-Z]|\d+)/g);`

I hope this makes sense! Appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you guarantee case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `replaceAll` with 3 alternations:

```
str = str.replace(/\b(\d+\b|\w{2}\b|\w)\w*\b */g, "$1");
```

**Code:**

```js
var arr = ['79 Banana AK', 'Lemon 99 B3']
var re = /\b(\d+\b|\w{2}\b|\w)\w*\b */g

arr.forEach(function(str) {
  console.log(str.replace(re, "$1"))
})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tKoXTR/2)

We match word boundary first then looks for all digits or just 2 characters words or else just first char of a word.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, When I try this regex it works for the first word and maintains the number but then it shows a random number based off the second word? I'm not to sure where that number is coming from. I updated my question to show how I am using my initial regex.

Comment: My bad. I thought it is Java code. I have updated to show Javascript regex and sample demo. Please check and let me know.